# Word document to PDF

Tags: pdf

I have a word (MS Word) document of containing ordered/un-ordered lists and tables. When I save/export this file as PDF it appears that, lists and tables are not converted as PDF TR/TD/TABLE tags and LI for lists, instead it is like regular position based printing.

I tried office 2007 and libreOffice both but i cannot see any table or list related objects in resultant PDF, when I open them in text editor.

is there a better way to create pdf file? or i am doing something wrong!

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with (La)TeX. You might try superuser.

Comment: Why would a `Word` table be converted to a `PDF` table?  This doesn't convert the Word objects into PDF objects.  If you want that functionality use Adobe Acrobat to convert the Word file to a PDF file.

Comment: @Ramhound but why it cannot do this, its just another way of representation when we already have object details?

Comment: @AbhishekK - Because Word doesn't understand how to convert the table into a PDF table.

Comment: is this limitation specific to word application, or some other printer or addon can do it. do you mean to say a mere PDF printer follow radically different approach than acrobat?